# Facebook Search Pages pages_read_engagment permission error

Tags: api, facebook, facebook-graph-api, backend

I'm trying to send a request to facebook api (search pages)

```
"(#10) This endpoint requires the 'manage_pages' or 'pages_read_engagement' permission or the 'Page Public Content Access' feature or the 'Page Public Metadata Access' feature. Refer to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login-permissions#manage-pages, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature#reference-PAGES_ACCESS and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature#page-public-metadata-access for details."
```

My app has gone a review and in the dashboard I can see that pages-read-engagement is active. In app domains I have entered my apps url.
That's the endpoint im trying to call:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/pages/search?q=Facebook&fields=id,name,location&access_token={app_id|secret}
```

What could cause this error?

Comment: Does the access token you using grant those permissions?

Comment: @WizKid I use my apps access_token - eg. {app_id}|{secret}.

Comment: You app access token doesn't have manage_pages or pages_read_engagement.